# what's the meaning of "To make the larger point"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "To make the larger point"

e.g.

> To make the larger point, this chapter initiates a detailed study of types of 
>   commercial and political alliance making that are impossible to generalize.

Answer (score 1):

*The larger point* refers to a wider context where you are acting, which you may disregard or neglect because you are too focused on your "smaller" issues.

The next few lines are taken from an article about "Vegans, who miss the larger point":

"In the mad dash to fill our lives with alternatives to animal industries, vegans tend to miss the greater point of a lifestyle dedicated to making the world a better place."